# Question about changing the number font

Tags: fonts

Hello from the following code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{fourier}    


\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{type1cm}


\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\rmfamily}
  {\sffamily\flushright\fontsize{60}{0}\textbf{\vskip50pt\textcolor{black}{~\thechapter\vskip0pt}}}{0pt}
  {\flushleft\fontsize{30}{0}{#1}\vskip60pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-40pt}{0pt}


\chapter{Test}


\end{document}
```

The font size of the number is fixed even though I change the font size. I found that the reason is because I am using \usepackage{fourier}  which I have been using throughout and have to use. How can I change the number size and design without deleting  \usepackage{fourier}?

Comment: As `fourier` uses `T1` font encoding, you must add `\usepackage{lmodern}` before `\usepackage{fourier}` (and remove `\usepackage{type1cm}`)... Or, remove `\sffamily` in your number format commands.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thank you so much!

Comment: @PaulGaborit Why loading `lmodern`? There no reason for.

Comment: @egreg The Latin Modern family is _very_ similar to the Computer Modern family (I forgot `fix-cm` existed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `fourier` uses `T1` font encoding, you must add `\usepackage{lmodern}` before `\usepackage{fourier}` (and remove `\usepackage{type1cm}`)...

Or, you can remove `\sffamily` in your number format commands.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `\usepackage{type1cm}` and use `fix-cm` instead. There are also several fixes to do with the `\titleformat` code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large}
  {\fontsize{60}{0}\sffamily\bfseries\filleft\thechapter}
  {50pt}
  {\filright\fontsize{30}{0}\selectfont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}
  {-40pt}
  {0pt}


\begin{document}


\chapter{Test}


\end{document}
```

[image]